# In Canada, is a crown corproation the same as a federal government corporation

Tags: canada, corporations, form-of-government

For example, the [CPPIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPP_Investment_Board) is listed as a crown corporation. Does this mean it is a public sector company? The same as a federal government company? 
I am considering applying for a job here. All I want to know is, if it will have the same generous pension and benefit policies that public sector companies are known for in Canada.

Comment: Good question, but isn't it more on-topic on Law.SE or Workplace.SE than Politics?

Comment: Crown corporations are indeed staffed through the same unions as the rest of the Federal government with virtually identical salaries, classifications, and benefits. Oddly, however, you will find that mobility from a crown corporation to a "true" federal department is not easy as they are generally not in the same staffing pools for competitions. You will find job listings for CPPIB on the same site as all other Federal Jobs: jobs.gc.ca

Comment: http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/what-are-crown-corporations-and-why-do-they-exist-1.1135699

Comment: @Michael: Thank you. Do you know if CPPIB offers RRSP matching? Their website has absolutely no information!

Comment: I don't believe so Victor as the public service already provides a very nice indexed pension. You can dig through some general details on the compensation and benefits here: www.tbs-sct.gc.ca/chro-dprh/index-eng.asp